# Xamarin forms: How to clear old distribution certificate and provisioning profile from ios bundle signing?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, provisioning-profile

I have two apple ids (A and B) and created a new distribution certificate and provisioning profile for my ios app from B's account. I copied this project from my old project which already mapped with A's distribution certificate and provisioning profiles.

Now I need to clear the old mappings(A's) and add B's distribution certificate and provisioning profile to my new app. I download the new distribution certificate and provisioning profile and install it to keychain access. But in ios bundle signing the new certificate and profiles are not listing.

So how can I clear the old distribution certificate and provisioning profile from ios bundle signing? I am using visual studio in Mac.

Comment: Are bundle id's same for both certificates?

Comment: @MilanG no, different bundle id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have following bundle ids per Apple id:

A : com.yourcompany.xxxxxx

B : com.yourcompany.yyyyyy

In the Mac, you need to install the new Certificate as well as the Provisioning Profile for this certificate.

Now, in your iOS project, open info.plist file and check which bundle id you have set. If you have set the bundle id from Apple Id - A, then you need to change this bundle id created from Apple Id - B.

Now go to iOS project Options -> iOS Bundle Signing -> you should be able to see your new distribution certificate in **Signing Identity** dropdown.

Once you select it, you should also be able to see the provisioning profile matching to this certificate in **Provisioning Profile** Dropdown.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My B account distribution was listing when I open the iOS Bundle Signing from info.plist -> Bundle Signing options. Then I choose both certificate and profile and it solved. Thanks for telling about info.plist...